# How to deal with this situation when picking a single owner from a list of owners using perl hashes?

Tags: algorithm, perl

I run perforce command on a list of files and after some parsing and stuff i generate a file that contains owners like this(call it owner.log):

```
ownerA
ownerB
ownerC
ownerA
ownerA
```

then i go throug the owner.log file and pick an owner like this:

```
while(<OWNER>) {
 $vote->{$_} += 1;
}
```

and then the owner with the highest vote gets selected for email notification. But the problem is when i have an owner log like this:

```
ownerA
ownerB
ownerC
ownerD
```

each one gets the same vote? How should i pick one?

Thank you.

Is there a quick way of finding if all hashes have same value? that way i can pick one at random.

Comment: However you like. Pick one at random. Return a list of all the owners with the same number of votes. Throw an exception and demand a revote. This seems to be a business logic decision and not a programming problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to determine if all hash keys have the same value is to use [uniq](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/List-MoreUtils-0.33/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm).  If there is only one common value, use the keys of your hash as an array and use `rand` to find a random index within the array bounds:

```
use More::ListUtils qw(uniq);
my @keys = keys   %hash;
my @vals = values %hash;
if (scalar uniq(@vals) == 1) {
    print "all of equal weight\n";
    print $keys[ int(rand(@keys)) ], "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the array `@winners`:

```
print "The winner is: ", $winners[rand @winners];
```

The whole process:

```
my $last = 0; 
my @winners;
for my $name (sort { $vote->{$b} <=> $vote->{$a} } keys %$vote) { 
    last if ($vote->{$name} < $last); 
    push @winners, $name; 
    $last = $vote->{$name};
} 

my $winner = $winners[rand @winners];

print "The winner is, by ", 
       @winners == 1 ? "unanimous vote: " : "luck of the draw: ", $winner;
```